# HTML2Canvas not rendering image in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, jspdf, html2canvas

I read other answers which told that images will render when we host it in the server. In my case I have the images coming dynamically from server. Its working perfect in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari. Here is my code using JsPDF and HTML2Canvas:

```
$(document).on('click', '#download_pdf', function(){
  $('.hide-pdf').hide();
  html2canvas(document.body,{
    useCORS: true,
    logging:true,
    onrendered:function(canvas){
      $('.loading-wrap').hide();
      var img=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      var imgWidth = 210;
      var pageHeight = 295;
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
      var heightLeft = imgHeight;

      var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
      var position = 0;

      doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      heightLeft -= pageHeight;

      while (heightLeft >= 0) {
        position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
        doc.addPage();
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
      }
      doc.save('bulldata.pdf');
    }
  }
  );
  $('.hide-pdf').show();
}
);
```

Can anyone help me to check **why images are not rendering only in Safari browser**.

Comment: You might want to define exactly what "not working" means...

Comment: Thanks for your response Steve. I have already mentioned in my question title that images are not rendering in Safari browser and also mentioned about the same in details. Will edit the last line also, if its confusing.

Comment: What I meant was - are you getting a blank/black image for example, no image at all. Would it be helpful for people to see a version of the correctly rendered image in a browser versus how it appears in safari. Are you getting errors from the console?

Comment: Please check the screenshot for logs: https://i.imgur.com/PAhmh0t.png , Chrome rendering correct pdf : https://i.imgur.com/6YP7Sln.png, safari missing the image : https://i.imgur.com/l1nHe29.png

Answer (score 1):

I'm also dealing with the same issue. I think that the problem might be caused by CORS option. Basically it works well without CORS option even though Safari.

https://helperbyte.com/questions/277332/as-safari-to-make-it-work-with-cors-html2canvas-correctly